# Management of a python OpenCV Window accross the different methods of a class

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I have some trouble with an OpenCV GUI I try to create for a small python application. The GUI is aimed to display an image, to create a set of toggle bars to tune some threshold values which will be use in an image processing algorithm and to display the transformed image next to the original image.

My idea is to manage the GUI through a python class and to store the different threshold values/parameters in the class attributes. I have a method which create the window that I call in the **init** method and then several other methods (such as one_step() for instance) doing some operations involving the window such as reading the toggle bar values displaying an image, etc ...

'''

```
def __init__(self, path_to_images):

    self._min_canny = 100
    self._max_canny = 200

    self._blur_kernel_size = 5
    self._blur_sigma_value = 0

    self._closing_iterations = 1

    self._path_to_images = path_to_images

    os.chdir(path_to_images)

    self._count = 1

    self._current_image = cv2.imread(str(self._count) + '.jpg' , 1)

    self.initialize_window()



def initialize_window(self):      

    cv2.namedWindow('Original')

    cv2.createTrackbar('Blur Kernel Size', 'Original', self.blur_kernel_size, 10, GUI_seg.on_change)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Blur Sigma Value', 'Original', self.blur_sigma_value, 5, GUI_seg.on_change)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Min Canny', 'Original', self.min_canny, 255, GUI_seg.on_change)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Max Canny', 'Original', self.min_canny, 255, GUI_seg.on_change)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Closing Iterations', 'Original', self.closing_iterations, 20, GUI_seg.on_change)

    self.one_step()
```

'''

But when I create an instance of the class and run methods involving the window, no window is opened by the program. I suspect a problem of memory space management (the window is created inside a function and at the end of the execution of the function).

If anyone as an idea of what is going on and how to fix this, I would really appreciate some help with this issue.

Comment: Can you explain what you are running and what output do you get?

Comment: Well, I run this three lines to create an instance object of the class described above:  `path_to_images = 'C:/Users/YVM1SGP/Documents/dataset3/selected_images'`  `gui = GUI_seg(path_to_images) `  `gui.run()`

Comment: The method run() is just a while (True) loop in which we retrieve the value of the different params with the toggle bars, update the object attributes, compute the new processed image and update the display in the window.

Comment: I expected to at least a window opened at the creation of the Gui_seg object but nothing is opened and the program keep running (the while loop) without threading any error